# SQL Server grouping data

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

One of our log table got result like below

```
Unique__Nm  reviewer 1    reviewer 2    reviewer 3
--------------------------------------------------
  859          NULL          NULL        Joel
  859          NULL         Joseph       NULL
  859         Antony         NULL        NULL
  163         Robert         NULL        NULL
  163          NULL         Joseph       NULL
  164          NULL         Andrew       NULL
  896          NULL          karry       NULL
```

I need to group data based on Unique number and extract result like below

```
Unique__Num  reviewer 1   reviewer 2    reviewer 3
------------------------------------------------
859            Antony     Joseph        Joel
163            Robert     Joseph        NULL
164            NULL       Andrew        NULL
896            NULL       Kerry         NULL
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO; can you please show what you have tried so far

Comment: i tried group by , it is not working

Comment: _it is not working_ This is NEVER a useful thing to write in a technical discussion. Post what you tried. Show what it produced (if anything). If you encounter an error, then post the complete error message - all of it.

Answer (score 2):

What if your input is like:

```
Unique__Nm  reviewer 1    reviewer 2    reviewer 3
--------------------------------------------------
  859          NULL          NULL        Joel
  859          NULL         Joseph       NULL
  859         Antony         NULL        NULL
  859          NULL         Edmund       NULL
```

What should be reviewer 2 in the output?

If such input is possible at all, you should specify what should happen, ie. what should we get as rewiever 2.

Otherwise this will do the work:

```
SELECT Unique__Nm, max([reviewer 1]), max([reviewer 2]), max([reviewer 3])
  FROM table
 GROUP BY Unique__Nm;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   Unique_Nm INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,[reviewer 1] VARCHAR(60)
  ,[reviewer 2] VARCHAR(60)
  ,[reviewer 3] VARCHAR(60)
);
INSERT INTO test
(Unique_Nm,[reviewer 1],[reviewer 2],[reviewer 3]) VALUES 
(859,NULL,NULL,'Joel'),
(859,NULL,'Joseph',NULL),
(859,'Antony',NULL,NULL),
(163,'Robert',NULL,NULL),
(163,NULL,'Joseph',NULL),
(164,NULL,'Andrew',NULL),
(896,NULL,'karry',NULL);
```

using provide `String_agg` provide better situation where exist two [reviwer] per Unique_Nm and it will `concat` them, In addition, it mask null values.

```
select Unique_Nm,
string_agg([reviewer 1],',') [reviewer 1],
string_agg([reviewer 2],',') [reviewer 2],
string_agg([reviewer 3],',') [reviewer 3]
from test
group by Unique_Nm
```

however using `Max` is also possible

```
select Unique_Nm,
MAX([reviewer 1]) [reviewer 1],
MAX([reviewer 2]) [reviewer 2],
MAX([reviewer 3]) [reviewer 3]
from test
group by Unique_Nm
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=56c648c4165ff666ab59b7aa6ef44758)

Answer (score 0):

If all of `reviewer 1`, `reviewer 2` and `reviewer 3` columns can have **only one not null** value per `Unique__Nm`, you can use simple `coalesce` per column grouped by  `Unique_Nm` values, e.g.

```
SELECT 
    Unique__Nm, 
    COALESCE([reviewer 1]) as [reviewer 1], 
    COALESCE([reviewer 2]) as [reviewer 2], 
    COALESCE([reviewer 3]) as [reviewer 3] 
FROM table 
GROUP BY Unique__Nm
```